# add checkbox to qtreewidgetitem

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidgetitem

i want to add a check box to my `qtreewigetitem`, i tried this code to `setflag`, then i add item is selectable for sake of maybe this will solve my problem but nothing happened, would you please help me how can i add `check box` to my item? 
thank you in advance

```
m_eventList->addTopLevelItem(new QTreeWidgetItem);
       QTreeWidgetItem *item = m_eventList->topLevelItem(m_eventList->topLevelItemCount()-1)

    item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable |Qt::ItemIsSelectable);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ItemIsUserCheckable flag is already set by default in QTreeWidgetItem, so that's not the issue.

All you need is to do

```
item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
```

and you should see a checkbox.

Answer (score 8):

Try to reorganize your code:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsSelectable);
item->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
m_eventList->addTopLevelItem(item);
```

Another method would be to write your own model and overwrite the [flags()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) method. In this method, you return

```
Qt::ItemFlags flags = Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
if (index.column() == 0)
{
    flags |= Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable;
}
return flags;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` and `Qt::ItemIsSelectable` are default setting for QTreeWidget.

`item->setCheckState(column, Qt::Unchecked)` is Okay.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#flags